# Equality of two complete measurable spaces under different measures.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ be finite measures on a measurable space $(X,A)$ and $A_\mu$ be the completion of $A$ under $\mu$.

Prove or disprove: $A_\mu = A_\nu$ if and only if $\mu$ and $\nu$ have exactly the same sets of measure zero.

I have shown that if $\mu$ and $\nu$ have exactly the same sets of measure zero then $A_\mu = A_\nu$, but I am unable to prove or disprove the opposite direction.

Please help.

Comment: What is $A_\mu$?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention.

Comment: Depending on how you define the completion, this might be trivial.

Comment: I used the definition:  The completion of $\mathscr{A}$ under $\mu$ is the collection $\mathscr{A}_\mu$ of subsets A of X for which there are sets $E$ and $F$ in$\mathscr{A}$ such that $E\subset A\subset F$ and $\mu (F-E)=0.$

Comment: Hint: What is $A_\mu$ if $\mu$ has finite support?

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Thank you. I took a finite set and two measures, point masses at different points. I gave the whole power set in both cases. Thank you.

Comment: The support is not (yet) defined in my textbook. Can you clarify how this helped you?